# Google Search Console Insights data vs real search data

Tags: google-search-console, search-results, google-ranking, google-insights

I have a small directory website and when I look at my Google Search Console Insights my website looks like the image below:

[image: google insight data]

Ranking is between 10-15, but in real searches my Google ranking is very low, mostly on page 5.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Have you cleared your browser cache?  Have you limited GSC to the country where you are searching from?  There's way too many variables to try and compare averages.

Also, Google's algorithm is somewhat adaptive.  If a user queries something similar, but then makes a different query a few minutes later, Google may attempt to redefine the results it provides since the first query didn't answer the users query.  Even the delay between the results Google displays in GSC (often several hours) and your live testing could impact and cause a difference in what you're seeing.